# Why the WriteElementString() doesn't put a new line in the xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

```cs
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Video");
        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("FileName", temp.nameFile);
        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("VideoName", temp.nameVideo);
        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Path", temp.path);
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

I wrote this part of code with c#, but when I'm going to check the result I see just one row without a new line anywhere!

How is it possible?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What do you mean "how is it possible"? They're different elements - there's no *need* to have a new line. Why do you think a new line would be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a new line with your xml writer then you should use xml settings like so:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
//this will auto indent as well as put everything on a new line
settings.Indent = true; 

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("file_Name.xml", settings);
writer.WriteStartDocument();

xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Video");
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("FileName", temp.nameFile);
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("VideoName", temp.nameVideo);
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Path", temp.path);
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pass in settings when constructing your xml writer so it behaves the way you want it to. Check **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx)** out for more information.